# ¿Cómo ejecutar un archivo SQL en Go?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, go

Tengo un archivo SQL que crea un Schema y todas sus tablas. El archivo (que es muy largo para ponerlo completo) comienza así:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS correos 
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 
COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci;


USE correos;


CREATE TABLE cartero (
  DNI VARCHAR(9),
  nombre VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  apellidos VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (DNI)
);

....
```

Cuando lo ejecuto con MySQL Workbench no me da ningún problema. Sin embargo, cuando lo quiero ejecutar utilizando Go con la siguiente función:

```
func initSchema(db *sql.DB) error {
    nombreArchivo := "create_schema.sql"
    bytesLeidos, err := ioutil.ReadFile(nombreArchivo)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error leyendo archivo: %v \n", err)
    }

    sqlSentence := string(bytesLeidos)

    // Preparamos para prevenir inyecciones SQL
    sentenciaPreparada, err := db.Prepare(sqlSentence)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer sentenciaPreparada.Close()

    // Ejecutar sentencia
    _, err = sentenciaPreparada.Exec()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
> use near 'USE correos;
>
> CREATE TABLE cartero (
> DNI VARCHAR(9),
> nombre VARCHAR(250) NO' at line 4

Siendo la linea 4 la siguiente

```
USE correos;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al momento de generar la conexión a MySQL, exista la opción de indicar si se aceptarán o no múltiples sentencias SQL en un solo llamado.

La documentación está en https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#multistatements

El parametro `multiStatements` debe incluirse en la cadena de conexión:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:pass@tcp(localhost:3306)/dbname?multiStatements=true")
```